# ActionScripts 3 How to replace/swap an image inside a stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, animate-cc

I have some PNG image on a stage in Animate CC, how to possible change/swap an image with another PNG that imported to Library with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add image from Library you need to set AS3 class (let it be image.flame) for that image and then

```
import image.flame;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var aRaster:BitmapData = new image.flame();
var aBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(aRaster);

aBitmap.name = "Flame";
addChild(aBitmap);
```

Removing is a bit more tricky, probably.

1) If Animate CC allows to name bitmap instances then you are in luck and can just name it (e.g. Flame) and then:

```
removeChild(getChildByName("Flame"));
```

**1.1) Also you can wrap that bitmap with a MovieClip and give it a proper name. I think it is the most reliable way.**

2) If Animate CC does not allow to name bitmaps, just as CS6 that I have doesn't, then you are up to few options.

2.1) If your bitmap is the only child in its container, just remove it with

```
removeChildAt(0);
```

2.2) If it is the only bitmap among some other content, you can find it and remove:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i ++)
{
    var aChild:Bitmap = getChildAt(i) as Bitmap;

    if (aChild)
    {
        removeChild(aChild);
        break;
    }
}
```

2.3) If that bitmap is one of many, and there are other content in this container, well... guess its depth and **removeChildAt(...)** it, or go for option #1.1 and wrap that bitmap with a MovieClip for it to have instance name and available for removal.

P.S. Just a side note, prior to CS6 I recall that Flash converted bitmaps (Bitmap class) into bitmap-filled shapes (Shape class), so #1.1 is your best friend anyway.

Comment: I converted Images to MovieClips now it's better to handle. You are right, working with Bitmaps is complex.